# How to ask for android permissions in a sequential manner?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

I am trying to make an android application where the permissions(for android 6.0 and above) are to be asked before the next activity is called.But every time I try, it goes to next activity and going back ,I see the permissions being asked.Is there any way to run permissions first and only once that is over,go to the next activity?

Comment: it will show popup if you not give permission as Granted.

Comment: Your permission prompt dialog is probably starting in order itself but being hidden behind the new activity, hence its visible when you close the new activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your activity only if the permission is granted, else ask for permission.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1){
    // Use your own required permission here instead of WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    if(!(getActivity().checkSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
        // Permission not already granted, Asking for permission
        String[] perms = {"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
        requestPermissions(perms, 200);
    }else {
        // Permission already granted, starting activity ...
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

`onRequestPermissionsResult()` is invoked when permission granted or denied from dialog by user. This can be used to handle the event when the user selects an option from permission prompt.

```
/**
Called when permission granted or denied
*/
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode){
        case 200:{
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                // Permission granted, starting activity ...
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Permission Denied by user. Please grant access to continue.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to grant permission (if permission not given) and then start activity instead of putting it in an else statement?

Comment: Nope! The permission must be granted/denied by the user. Hence its called 'permission'. :D

Comment: I meant like,check if permissions are granted ,grant them if not already, otherwise skip.Then immediately start activity

Comment: I think I know what you mean. Why not start the activity right after the `requestPermissions(perms, 200)` call right?
Well the flow here doesn't work sequentially since alerts/prompts in Android are not waited upon, rather they have separate listeners/callbacks (Not sure why, but probably because it would block the UI thread). 
Here `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is the callback for the permission prompt.

Comment: Oh ok.That was actually my doubt.I guess I'll use your answer instead